# adding a scope to ActiveRecord::Base via initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, initializer, scoping

I've tried to add a scope like this, via an initializer

```
class ActiveRecord::Base        
  scope :this_month,  lambda { where(:created_at => Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month) }
end
```

But Im getting the error "NoMethodError: undefined method `abstract_class?' for Object:Class". What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding a class while you should be doing it through the module. 
I would also be a bit careful with this approach since you are reling on every model having created_at

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    scope :this_month,  lambda { where(:created_at => Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month) }
  end
end
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the actual initializer code you have as well as the location of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version you can include in a initializer  like `app/initializer/active_record_scopes_extension.rb`.

And just call `MyModel.created(DateTime.now)` or `MyModel.updated(3.days.ago)`.

```
module Scopes
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def self.created(date_start, date_end = nil)
          if date_start && date_end
            scoped(:conditions => ["#{table_name}.created_at >= ? AND #{table_name}.created_at <= ?", date_start, date_end])
          elsif date_start
            scoped(:conditions => ["#{table_name}.created_at >= ?", date_start])
          end
      end
      def self.updated(date_start, date_end = nil)
          if date_start && date_end
            scoped(:conditions => ["#{table_name}.updated_at >= ? AND #{table_name}.updated_at <= ?", date_start, date_end])
          elsif date_start
            scoped(:conditions => ["#{table_name}.updated_at >= ?", date_start])
          end
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, Scopes)
```